# Lendo código de barras no react-native

Tags: mobile, react-native, código-de-barras

Como faço para ler código de barras pela câmera do celular com react-native?

Comment: Olá Fernando, seja bem vindo ao SO, por favor veja o tour do site para entender como ele funciona. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Também precisei de um componente que atendesse minhas necessidades. Encontrei esse, ainda não sei se é bom. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scan-barcode

Comment: A resposta original me deu um norte, más a documentação original não estava tão clara pra mim que sou iniciante, então achei essa matéria! Foi o que me ajudou! 
https://medium.com/@goodpic/rncamera-as-a-free-barcode-scanner-lib-for-react-native-110fa0c610af

Answer (score 1):

Documentação e api: [react-native-camera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/RNCamera.md)

O resto é com voce